# removing format of a given image as an string

Tags: javascript

let's say we have a variable containing a string representing an image and its format like this:

```
let pictureLabel = 'picture.jpg';
```

I want a function to remove the format and return the name only. so I tried this but definitely I need a hand as a beginner :)

**Here is what I tried without success. Why and how to fix this code:**

```js
let pictureLabel = 'picture.jpg';


function withoutFormat(pictureLabel){

  const formats = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif']; // defined formats to be remove
  
  formats.forEach(format => {
  
  console.log(pictureLabel.lastIndexOf(`.${format}`))
    
  if(pictureLabel.lastIndexOf(`.${format}`) != -1){
     return pictureLabel.substring(0, pictureLabel.lastIndexOf(`.${format}`));
  
  } 
    
  });
   
}

console.log(withoutFormat(pictureLabel));
```

Comment: U can use regex, indexof  or split methods. It is based on your input types. @foxer

Comment: What error or inaccurate results are you getting with the new code you just posted?

Comment: I think the problem is your return statement doesn't return from `withoutFormat`, it returns from the anonymous function `format => { ... }`.

Comment: If  you replace your `formats.forEach` with a normal for loop (or maybe `for format of formats`) it will probably work, I think.

Comment: Well, technically `for(format of formats) {...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if u will do all types for your files use split and take first element

```js
let pictureLabel = 'picture.jpg';

console.log(pictureLabel.split(".")[0])
```

but if it will be just for spesific ones use regex

```js
var array=[".png",".jpg"];

console.log("picture.jpg".replace(new RegExp(array.join("|")),""))
console.log("video.mp4".replace(new RegExp(array.join("|")),""))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using node.js, use [`path.basename`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext).

Otherwise, [`Array.prototype.lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) seems like a good way to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

use lastindexof() method to find the last(.) and remove the string after the (.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this function now.

```
function withoutFormat(pictureLabel) {

    const formats = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif']; // defined formats to be remove
    // Code to remove the format and return the name
    let lastIndexOfDot = pictureLabel.lastIndexOf('.');
    let name = pictureLabel.slice(0, lastIndexOfDot);
    let ext = pictureLabel.slice(lastIndexOfDot + 1, pictureLabel.length);
    if (formats.includes(ext))
        return name;
    return 'Image format not defined';
}
let pictureLabel = 'picture.png';
console.log(withoutFormat(pictureLabel));
```

Comment: plus one... I would be thankful if you have a look at the edit of my question...

Comment: Yeah idk what the deal is with that. Maybe that's someone's way of promoting their own answer... :S

Answer (score 0):

In response to the new question:

The return statement appears to be returning from the anonymous function defined inside `formats.forEach(format => {...})`. Perhaps the easiest way to fix it would be to use a `for (format of formats) {` instead of the `foreach()` function. Then the enclosed `return` statement will return from the broader-scoped `withoutFormat` as I think is intended.

For the original question:
Try `"picture.jpg".replace(/\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,'')`

Regex breakdown:

- `\.` a dot
- `(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)` one of the file extensions
- `$` the end of the string

Comment: This is a great idea, I would be thankful if you have a look at the edit of my question...

Comment: I think you need to give more information about what you want. You have several working answers to your problem but you’ve updated your question to say vaguely “this code doesn’t work. Fix it.”  If you are going to update your question, update it with more info on what you want or what errors or inaccurate results you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let pictureLabel = 'picture.jpg';

function withoutFormat(file){
  const formats = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'];
  const regex = new RegExp(`.(${formats.join("|")})$`, 'gi');  
  return file.replace(regex, "");
}

console.log(withoutFormat(pictureLabel));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const filename = "demo.heic"
const newFileName = `${filename.split('.')[0]}.jpeg`
console.log(newFileName)

//======== OR ==========================//
 
const filename1 = "image.BMP"
const array = ['bmp', 'BMP', 'pjp', 'jfif', 'heic', 'HEIC']
const checkFileExtension = filename1.split('.').pop()
console.log(checkFileExtension)
if (array.includes(checkFileExtension)) {
  console.log(`${filename1.split('.')[0]}.jpeg`)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: You answer would be correct if the question was how to replace the image file extension. The question is "I want a function to remove the format and return the name only." what makes your answer close to what s/he wants to achieve but not correct.